# How to mock return model using autofixture?

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit, autofixture

I have an error in `Assert` statements: `Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times` and `assert.equal` returns `false`.

The order of parameters is true and mock is frozen. Help to figure out what is going wrong? Below my xUnit code and testedModule:

```
public async Task<GeolocationDataResponse> GetById(int Id)
{
    var user = await _dbRepository.GetBy(x => x.Id == Id);
    if (user is null)
        return null;
    var userResponse = _mapper.Map<UserResponse>(user );
    return userResponse;
} 


public class UserProviderTests
   {
[Theory, UserProviderTestsData]
public async void GetById_ReturnSuccess(
    User user,
    [Frozen] Mock<IDbRepository<User>> dbRepoMock,
    UserProvider sut
    )
{
    int id = user.Id;
    dbRepoMock.Setup(x => x.GetBy(v => v.Id == It.IsAny<int>())).ReturnsAsync(user);

     var response = await sut.GetById(id);

     Assert.Equal(response.Id, id);
     dbRepoMock.Verify(x => x.GetBy(v => v.Id == It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);
}

internal class UserProviderTestsDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public UserProviderTestsDataAttribute()
        : base(
            () =>
            {
                var fixture = new Fixture();
                fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true });
                fixture.Customize(new UserProviderTestsCustomization ());
                return fixture;
            })
    {
    }
}

internal class UserProviderTestsCustomization : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        fixture.Register(() =>
            new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.AddProfile(new UserAutomapper()); }).CreateMapper());
    }
 }
}
```

When I have debugged, I noticed that `GetBy` returns model with differen `Id` than is defined in `Mock.Setut().ReturnAsync(user)`

Comment: I’m not sure your setup makes sense. Have your tried: dbMockRepo.Setup(t=>t.GetById(id).ReturnsAsync(user)

Answer (score 0):

The code posted doesn't compile.  Is the Id a string or an int?  This version does compile and pass:

```
public class UserProviderTests
{
    [Theory]
    [AutoMoqData]
    public async void GetById_ReturnSuccess(
        User user,
        [Frozen] Mock<IDbRepository<User>> dbRepoMock,
        UserProvider sut)
    {
        int id = user.Id;
        dbRepoMock.Setup(t => t.GetById(id)).ReturnsAsync(user);

        var response = await sut.GetById(id);

        Assert.Equal(response.Id, id);
        dbRepoMock.Verify(x => x.GetById(id), Times.Once);
    }
}

public interface IDbRepository<T> where T : User
{
    Task<T> GetById(int id);
}

public class UserProvider
{
    private readonly IDbRepository<User> _repository;

    public UserProvider(IDbRepository<User> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public async Task<User> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await _repository.GetById(id);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

internal class AutoMoqData : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqData()
        : base(
            () =>
            {
                var fixture = new Fixture();
                fixture.Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
                return fixture;
            })
    {
    }
}
```